# jquery: problem with the hashchange with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, load, hashchange

I am using an onhashchange plugin, but I have a problem to get it right when I want to load pages through ajax.

Here is my jquery,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).hashchange(function() {
        var hash = location.hash;
        var array_url = hash.split('#');
        var page = $(array_url).last()[0];
        $('#content').load( page + '.php', function(){
        });
    });

    $('.clickme').click(function(){

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var array_url = url.split('#');
        var page = $(array_url).last()[0];

        location.hash = url;

        $('#content').load( page + '.php', function(){
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

the html,

```
<a href="#1" class="clickme">1<a>
<a href="#2" class="clickme">2<a>

<div id="content">
</div>
```

The problem is the ajax page will be loaded twice or more when the link is clicked after the `hash` has changed.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using functions from jQuery wrappers on arrays?  Don't you know there are built-in methods to do that, e.g. `array_url.pop()`?

Comment: @neal: how do I put a log? what is the syntax? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the load twice:

```
$(window).hashchange(function() {
    var hash = location.hash;
    var array_url = hash.split('#');
    var page = $(array_url).last()[0];
    $('#content').load( page + '.php', function(){ //ONCE
    });
});

$('.clickme').click(function(){

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var array_url = url.split('#');
    var page = $(array_url).last()[0];

    location.hash = url; //GOTO HASH CHANGE ^^

    $('#content').load( page + '.php', function(){  //TWICE
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: The click event handler isn't required at all. `hashchange` should fire when the links are clicked.

Comment: @AndyE -- that is true as well, the OP might need it for some other operations

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the $('#content').load() call inside of the click listener. That way when you change the hash, only the hashchange listener will take care of the ajax call.